Which is bigger, 寨or 街道?
Source: 《南方周末》：记者从贵州毕节织金县人民政府新闻办公室获悉，10月1日16时50分左右，织金县金凤街道平寨社区湾子头组发生山体垮塌，造成1辆途经车辆（载有5人）和1名行人失联。
Is 寨(village)part of a 街道(street) but not the contrary?
Isn't it normal that in a village there can be one or more streets?
What are the relations of 县——街道——寨——社区——头组 in this case?

平寨 is the name of the 社区.

{贵州(省)}{毕节(市)} - {织金县}{金凤街道}{平寨社区}{湾子头组} ...

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_China#Summary
In this sentence, 街道 should be translated as subdistrict, rather than street.
The segmentation should be 织金县金凤街道平寨社区湾子头组
Note that 组 refers to villager group. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villages_of_China#Rural

You would have the order of 省，市，县，镇，寨，村，屯，街，宅。
街道 would be a subdivision in a 县城。区 would be a subdivision in a 城市。街道 could also be a subdivision in a 区。街道委员会 can administer a few of 社区（大院，宿舍，小区）。
The ways to call the places are much different in countryside and in big cities. But in some cities, they still keep the historical names of the old towns and villages。
